# Issue storing command line arguments in text file

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on a program where the user needs to be able store the command line arguments in a text file.  This is because the command to run the program can be very long.  Here is a simplified example of what I want.

```
./myprogram "this is one command" another command
```

When I run this my program should print each command one a single line.

I get the following expected output

```
this is a command
another
command
```

However now say I create a text file (config.txt) containing `"this is one command" another command`

I then go to run my program like `./myprogram $(cat config.txt)`

I would expect this to produce the same output but it does not.  The first line of the output reads...

```
"this
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it.

Comment: Word splitting problem. Paradoxically, bash is not a very good language for parsing bash code... `eval "./myprogram $(<config.txt)"` will work in this case (`$(< file)` is shorthand for `$(cat file)`), but `eval` is very risky.

Comment: Actually, can you tell us why you want to achieve this in the first place? Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: The actual program is for stacking astronomical images.  The images are passed to the command line like `stacker -lights (1000 image file names) -darks (a bunch more file) -script "dcraw -c %s"`  It is the script part I am having trouble with since it contains the quotes.  As you can see the arguments can get very long and it makes more sense to store them in a text file sometimes.  Also there are use cases where you might want to say something like `stacker -lights $(ls *.jpg)` so I don't want to take a text file only approach.

Comment: What do you mean by wild-card?

Comment: Re: your edit to your comment: there's never a use case where you need `$(ls *.jpg)` as command line arguments. As I said above, wildcard: `*.jpg`.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion

Comment: Oh.  I did not know bash handled that.  I always thought that my code would get *.jpg and I would have to handle that. But still this does not solve my main problem.

Comment: Then say what's your problem.

Comment: I need to be able to use text files to store command line arguments.  There a a lot of cases where you need to list out all the file and the *.jpg approach does not work for that.  Also the eval approach does not work either since I store the command line args with new lines after them so eval tries to execute each as a program.  My original approach only works if there are no arguments which need quotes to escape them.

Comment: Filename expansion is flexible enough to handle a lot of cases. "I store the command line args with new lines after them": why do you mix space and newline then (you used space as delimiter in your example above — I didn't make that up)? One filename per line, then we can read the file, put things into an array and expand. If you insist on mixing space and newline, and insist on "quoting" inside your semi-data, semi-code file, then only god can help you.